# I am trying to get to close my drop menu within the bars button in the responsive layout when less then 1500px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am pretty new to writing code and I am trying to make a navigation bar that has a drop menu when the screen is less than 1500px but I am trying to get it to close whenever I click outside its container. I have tried to use javascript that I have seen in youtube videos but it does not work so perhaps I am doing it wrong and I am getting really frustrated with this. Here is my code and I really hope you can help me. I didn't add any of the code that I have tried because I want to get new ideas without being affected or influenced by the ones that I have tried and if you could explain how I can add the code the right way so it properly works I will be really grateful. Thank you!

```css
/*display bars menu and hide the menu*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1464px)
{
    .navbar a:not(.resImg)
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar a.icon
    {
        float: right;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 8px;
    }
    .logoImg
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: none; 
    }
    .logoImg img
    {
        padding: 6px !important;
    }     
    div.mainMenu
    {
        padding: 0 !important; /*removes the extra padding when the menu is closed*/
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }   
    
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon.*/
@media screen and (max-width:1464px)
{
    .navbar.responsive {position: relative;}
    .navbar.responsive a.icon
    {
        position: inherit;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .navbar.responsive .mainMenu a
    {
        float:none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
/*CSS for the navbar*/
nav.navbar 
{
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #595959;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*div for the img logo and bars menu*/
.logoImg
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
}
/*logo img*/
.resImg img
{
    padding: 9px  7px 7px 7px;
    position: fixed;
}
.resImg img:hover
{
    background-color: indianred;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*css for bars icon*/
.icon
{
    display: none;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 19px 15px;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
.icon:hover
{
    background-color: indianred;
}

/*list of main menu*/
div.mainMenu 
{
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 13%;
}
div.mainMenu a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px 5px;
}
div.mainMenu a:hover
{
    background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
       <nav class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
            <div class=logoImg>
                <a class="resImg"><img class="active" src="images/logo.jpeg" height="64" width="173" /></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="mainMenu">
                <a>option 1</a>
                <a>option 2</a>
                <a>option 3</a>
                <a>option 4</a>
                <a>option 5</a>
                <a>option 6</a>
                <a>option 7</a>
                <a>option 8</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        
        <script>
            /*add the responsive class to the navbar when the user clicks on the bar button*/
            function myFunction()
            {
                var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
                if (x.className === "navbar")
                    {
                        x.className += " responsive";
                    }
                else
                    {
                        x.className = "navbar";
                    }
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
/*display bars menu and hide the menu*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1464px)
{
    .navbar a:not(.resImg)
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar a.icon
    {
        float: right;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 8px;
    }
    .logoImg
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: none; 
    }
    .logoImg img
    {
        padding: 6px !important;
    }     
    div.mainMenu
    {
        padding: 0 !important; /*removes the extra padding when the menu is 
closed*/
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }   
    
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the 
user clicks on the icon.*/
@media screen and (max-width:1464px)
{
    .navbar.responsive {position: relative;}
    .navbar.responsive a.icon
    {
        position: inherit;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .navbar.responsive .mainMenu a
    {
        float:none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
/*CSS for the navbar*/
nav.navbar 
{
    width: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #595959;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*div for the img logo and bars menu*/
.logoImg
{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    background-color: #4e4e4e;
}
/*logo img*/
.resImg img
{
    padding: 9px  7px 7px 7px;
    position: fixed;
}
.resImg img:hover
{
    background-color: indianred;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*css for bars icon*/
.icon
{
    display: none;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 23px;
    padding: 19px 15px;
    margin: 4px 0;
}
.icon:hover
{
    background-color: indianred;
}

/*list of main menu*/
div.mainMenu 
{
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 13%;
}
div.mainMenu a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 25px 5px;
}
div.mainMenu a:hover
{
    background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
        <div class=logoImg>
            <a class="resImg"><img class="active" src="images/logo.jpeg" 
height="64" width="173" /></a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" 
onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mainMenu">
            <a>option 1</a>
            <a>option 2</a>
            <a>option 3</a>
            <a>option 4</a>
            <a>option 5</a>
            <a>option 6</a>
            <a>option 7</a>
            <a>option 8</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    
    <script>
        /*add the responsive class to the navbar when the user clicks on the 
bar button*/
        function myFunction()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
            if (x.className === "navbar")
                {
                    x.className += " responsive";
                }
            else
                {
                    x.className = "navbar";
                }
        }
        document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            var x = document.getElementById('myNavbar');
            var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('mainMenu');
            var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');
            
            if(e.target.parentNode != x1[0] && x.className === 'navbar' + ' ' 
+ 'responsive' && e.target != x2[0]) {
                x.className = 'navbar'; //guessing this is what closes it.
                //console.log(e.target);
            }
        });

    </script>
```

You can try using

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    var x = document.getElementById('myNavbar');
    var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('mainMenu');
    var x2 = document.getElementsByClassName('icon'); 

    if(e.target.parentNode != x1[0] && x.className === 'navbar responsive' && e.target != x2[0]) {
        x.className = 'navbar'; //guessing this is what closes it.
        //console.log(e.target);
    }
});
```

The function fires when you click on the page, and checks if you haven't clicked on the navigation bar.

**EDIT** -> Took me forever to realize what you were doing. Changed the code now. Enjoy :) **P.S.** Try using ids instead of classes.

Comment: I have tried the eventListener and there is where I find the problem that I have no idea on how to approach because I don't know much about js. The thing is that the drop menu is on its own container the "mainMenu" and that is the one that I need to close while leaving alone the "navbar" because otherwise the whole container of the navigation bar disappears and you need to reload the page to be able to see it again

Comment: I don't understand. The button is triggering myFunction() which closes/opens the options menu, so I copied that but instead always closes it if e.target != x.

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it!
Although I don't understand why arrays are needed, I am confused... perhaps I am asking too much now that you helped me but could you explain to me why the need of arrays to close the menu? I do understand that the differents x's represent each item which is the navbar, menu and icon but why the arrays? I dont get that

Comment: Well, when we use the function getElementsByClassName(), it returns an array, but I just want the first element, so i use the element in index 0. If they were ids instead of classes maybe I wouldn't need arrays.

Comment: Could you also help me to figure out how to close the menu when an option has been selected? could I use the if statement with arrays as you did to close the menu when one of them has been selected or should I switch to ids instead of keep using the classes?

Comment: Well, I use classes for groups and ids for a specific element, so if you've made a class which is for 1 element only, you probably should use ids. (If you want to style ids, use #ID-NAME instead of .ID-NAME (notice ids have '#' instead of '.') And do you mean select as in when an option is clicked?

Comment: I will try to use ids instead of classes from now on and yes, close the menu after an option has been clicked and the page directed to the location within the page.